# Is it possible for an Asp.Net Core Web Application to be integrated with local storage?

Tags: file, asp.net-core

I have the below working on local host. However when I publish to azure the connection to my network doesn't work? I guess, this is obvious - my web app doesn't have connection to my local network. My question is, is there a way to allow a connection?

```
            try
            {
                var path = "//192.168.49.14/Data/18 Customer Requests/Customer Request System/Request Letters/";

                //Fetch all files in the Folder (Directory).
                string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine(path));

                //Copy File names to Model collection.
                var localFileList = new List<FileData>();
                var assocFiles = new List<FileData>();
                var linkedFiles = new List<FileData>();

                assocFiles = localFileList.Where(x => x.FileName.Contains(id.ToString())).ToList();

                foreach (var filePath in filePaths)
                {
                    localFileList.Add(new FileData { FileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath) });
                }

                assocFiles = localFileList.Where(x => x.FileName.Contains(id.ToString())).ToList();
                foreach (var item in assocFiles)
                {
                    linkedFiles.Add(new FileData { FileName = Path.GetFileName(item.FileName) });
                }

                ViewBag.localFiles = linkedFiles;
            }
            catch
            {
                ;
            }
            return View(Complaint);
```

Comment: Yes, there's ways. However - why? Can you not upload those files to some cloud native storage, such as Azure Blob storage?

Comment: Yes, I've implement blob storage solutions for clients. This particular client wants files to be stored locally.

Comment: Then you'll have to look into VPN options or hosting a secure API or SFTP server on the client's network that you expose to the public internet. Those are silly workarounds though. You say the client wants it this way: have them provide the reason for these decisions. That will help you come up with a better solution or make a persuasive case why that's not practical.